# How can I control this button?

Tags: android, button, dialog

I had a customized dialog and I put some button on it, the XML file of the dialog is like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="350sp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Confirm PSD"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="194dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout5"
    android:layout_width="254dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="127dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and this is my code:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Wify Setting");
dialog.show();
```

It displayed just like what I want, but when I set OnClick(Method name) property in the button1 it doesn't work and the app crashed, even if I use findViewById(R.id.button1) to find the button and set OnClickListener on it, it still will not work and crash.

Why is that?

Comment: Please define "crash". Are you getting an exception? If so, please post it here otherwise it's very difficult to help you.

Comment: This is why you **DONT** copy code... You reference, don't just copy blindly.

Comment: crash....is that the app forced to shut down by system

Comment: the exception is that it can't find the Method.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1)** .

It will work.

Thanks.